# Can u record if someone uses Google Chrome print?

Tags: php, html, web

I am thinking about making a forum with users.

When a user uses the Google Chrome web browser and tries to print a part of my web page(Article) can I record that?

For instance, store the information as 1(used CTRL+P) and 0(didn't use CTRL+P).

Comment: What this has to do with a forum?

Comment: It's a example, I am trying to find out if u can record the users action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only track this for statistics purposes then you can use CSS media print that will be triggered only for printing.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

```
<div id="print_stats"></div>

<style>
@media print {
  #print_stats {
    background-image: url(URL_TO_BACKEND_SCRIPT);
  }
}
</style>
```

PHP side depends of your needs - what you want to track.

Comment: Thank you very much, u answered my question fully.